# Google colab memory becomes full after image dataset is uploaded

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I am working on a classification problem with an image dataset, having 11 classes. It contains a total of 11,000 images, with each class having 1000 images, stored folder-wise (11 folders). The dataset size is about 40MB. After I upload the data from google drive into collab( which actually takes some time) and pre-process it before feeding it to the model, the memory of collab becomes 95% full instantaneously. When I start training, collab crashes, and the runtime is reset.
This does not happen when I use Keras data-flow-from-directory function. I am unable to find a solution. [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OgZPUol-DzzXdcMbec18NESrxfgEDHzf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do it in batches rather than all at once

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because by calling fit with the train and validation datasets you are forcing colab to load all the images on the ram at the same this, you need to write a generator, an easy solution with most of the code already written is to use the tfrecords, keras will handle the rest.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord

you need to store the images on disk and take them during the training, not all at the start.

Comment: you dont have to use tfrecords, you can use any generator you like, but that stuff comes right off the bat

Comment: Well I am using Keras Tuner here, so I am not sure if generator can be used with tuner-search or not